# How to make an application with a window without decorators (no close, minimize, maximize buttons as well as no border)

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need to implement a simple Mac OS X application with a Webview in in. Sounds simple, but this app should have no border or titlebar nor should it have any buttons at the top like max/minimize and close. More like a Widget.

A plus would be if I could set up my own controls (I need to close it somehow after all).

Is this actually possible? If yes: how?

Note: I have no experience with mac apps whatsoever. I know principally how it's done, but actually I never did anything with it. I there's a problem to my posted solution though, I will learn what is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create windows with no decorations, in the interface builder portion of Xcode just uncheck `Close`, `Minimize`, `Resize` and `Title Bar`. This will leave you with a window that has no decorations but still has a drop shadow.

With this type of setup, however, you will not have any window controls, and if you add custom buttons to close the window they will not link up with your menu items for close, zoom or minimize.

Also, you will probably want to set the `movableByWindowBackground` property of your window to `YES`, otherwise the user will not be able to move it.

If you wish to have a custom window design (custom close, zoom, minimize buttons) with the ability to customize the titlebar, I would highly reccommend INAppStoreWindow[1] for the task. I am using it in my project to great effect!

[1]https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow

Comment: Sounds good. Will test this soon. BTW: Are there any simple tutorials which explain how to do a webview with XCode 5? Just found some for earlier versions.

Comment: Please ask that as another question here on the site, as we are not supposed to have discussions or answer other questions in the comments. :)